# No keyboard response in applications due to permissions of /.config/ibus/bus

Tags: keyboard, permissions

I was running into an error using the Android SDK-- the error message was:

```
The owner of /home/[username]/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

So, like a moron I did a `sudo chown root:root /bus` command.

Now, I can type in the search bar, but not in any application (including terminal).  Any way to fix this permission?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in then run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME
```